# Microsoft.AspNet vs Microsoft.AspNetCore nuget packages?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, identityserver3, coreclr

I have ASP.NET Core application and application is using OpenIDConnect authentication. I use IdentityServer3 as an authentication server. I am little confused with which NuGet packages I should be using in ASP.NET Core for authentication & authorization.

The article [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/03/15/get-started-with-asp-net-core-authorization-part-1-of-2/) suggests using `Microsoft.AspNet.*****`, so something like below

```
     Microsoft.AspNet.Authorization
     Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.Cookies 
     Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
```

However, there is also the following NuGet package which looks like it is specific to .NET Core.

```
     Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
     Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies   
     Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect;
```

What is the difference between these packages and which should I be using for OpenIdConnect Authentication in ASP.NET Core?

Answer (score 9):

`Microsoft.AspNet.*` packages are obsolete now. Until RC the packages where named like that, with RC they were renamed to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.*` to avoid confusion and make it clear that ASP.NET Core is a complete new Framework and not compatible with previous ASP.NET MVC Stack. With it, all versions were reset to 1.0.0. (before the MVC packages would be versioned 6.0.0).

Same applies to `Microsoft.EntityFramework.*` which is now `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.*`. Also don't use any tutorials which are written with the rc1 or beta versions of ASP.NET Core. Too much changed for them to still be accurate and useful.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any sample code you can point me to which is doing authentication using OpenIDConnect and authorization

Comment: PinpointTownes has actually some samples on how to authenticate against the OpenIdConnect Server he is developing, but it should also work with identity server 4, because the MVC.Client project has no references to OpenIdConnect Server packages. See https://github.com/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Samples/blob/master/samples/Mvc/Mvc.Client/Startup.cs#L33-L50